# $scope array not updating in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-scope

I have an array of movies defined as a $scope variable, $scope.moviesList. I initialized all of the imageSrc fields for each object in the array to '' (empty string) and want to update this field for each object using the following function (the API key has been blanked out):

```
//loadMoviePosters calls the movie API for each movie in the moviesList array
//and sets the imageSrc field to the Poster link returned
$scope.loadMoviePosters = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.moviesList.length; i++) {
        var movie = $scope.moviesList[i];
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + movie.title + "&apikey=XXXXXXX"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            if (response.data.Poster != "N/A") {
                movie.imageSrc = response.data.Poster;
            }
            else {
                movie.imageSrc = '';
            }
            $scope.moviesList[i] = movie;
            //alert($scope.moviesList[i].imageSrc);
        },
        function error(respnonse) {
            //do nothing
        })
    }
    alert($scope.moviesList[0].imageSrc);
}
```

When I uncomment the alert inside of the for loop, it displays the image link for each object in the array, but the alert outside of the for loop always displays an empty string. It looks like the $scope.moviesList array is not actually being updated in this function.

In my HTML, I have the following code which I want to display the poster for each movie after this function updates the $scope array:

```
<div ng-repeat = "movie in moviesList">
                <img ng-src = "{{movie.imageSrc}}" />
                <p>{{movie.title}}</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can get the loadMoviePosters function to actually update the $scope.moviesList array? And then how can I get these images to show up in the ng-repeat? Thanks!

Comment: Because it's asynchronous.  The http request hasn't finished by the time it gets to that alert.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. After all the asynchronous calls have finished, how would I get the image in the ng-repeat div to reference the updated array?

Comment: Angular's change detection should automatically rebuild the view when it detects that the moviesList is changed.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but it is not happening